# Excel VBA loop code not working

Tags: vba, excel, loops, while-loop

This code does not work for the loop. I cant figure out why. I know its something simple but can't see it. The spreadsheet names are correct. When I run it, it works but has to debug everytime.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim X As Integer
    Dim Y As Integer
    Dim Z As Integer
    Dim Count As Integer

    X = 17
    Y = 2
    Z = 1
    Count = 4560

    Do While Z < Count
        If Sheets("Ind").Range("A" & X) = 1 Then
            Sheets("Returns").Range("A" & Y) = Sheets("Ind").Range("D" & X)
            Sheets("Returns").Range("B" & Y) = "Buy"
            Y = Y + 1
        ElseIf Sheets("Ind").Range("C" & X) = 2 Then
            Sheets("Returns").Range("A" & Y) = Sheets("Ind").Range("D" & X)
            Sheets("Returns").Range("B" & Y) = "Sell"
            Y = Y + 1
        End If
        X = X + 1
        Z = Z + 1
        Y = Y + 0
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: Works for me from a form and a worksheet.

Comment: It keeps telling me to debug.  Could it be the formating like the indentations?

Comment: Do you have a breakpoint set?

Comment: It's not the formatting (formatting it usually quite irrelevant in VBA).

Comment: What is the error number/description?

Comment: "It keeps telling me to debug" -- this means that a runtime error has occurred. The message has an error number and description. We need this, and the code line that is highlighted.

Comment: Exactly... Info needed: Error Number and Description; Highlighted line, Value of Z when the program breaks. To do that you simply need to read the message that tells you to debug (for the err num & description), then click debug and look at the line in yellow, then hover the cursor over Z (and it will present the current value of Z).

Answer (score 0):

Without error number and description (and without knowing the line where it breaks and the value of Z at that point) it's hard to determine the cause of the issue.

In any case: you can bypass the error (as long as you see that it didn't mess up the end result).

**DISCLAIMER:** This will will not solve your problem, it will simply bypass it. Be careful, because this may result in your code not executing with some of the combinations of variables. It is recommended that you actually try to fix your code instead of putting a band-aid on it.

**Just add:**

*On Error GoTo Looper*

**And before updating the variables add:**

*On Error GoTo 0*

*Looper:*

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Your code with the error handlers mentioned above:

```vb
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim X As Integer
Dim Y As Integer
Dim Z As Integer
Dim Count As Integer

X = 17
Y = 2
Z = 1
Count = 4560
On Error GoTo Looper
Do While Z < Count
    If Sheets("Ind").Range("A" & X) = 1 Then
        Sheets("Returns").Range("A" & Y) = Sheets("Ind").Range("D" & X)
        Sheets("Returns").Range("B" & Y) = "Buy"
        Y = Y + 1
    ElseIf Sheets("Ind").Range("C" & X) = 2 Then
        Sheets("Returns").Range("A" & Y) = Sheets("Ind").Range("D" & X)
        Sheets("Returns").Range("B" & Y) = "Sell"
        Y = Y + 1
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
Looper:
    X = X + 1
    Z = Z + 1
    Y = Y + 0
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend against this, it is better to identify and fix the error rather than just jumping past it.

Comment: You are absolutely right. But without knowing the actual source of the error this is the best I can do. If the end result seems good then maybe the error was on a condition where the loop should not be run in the first place.

Comment: I see your point but I think prompting the user for more info and hand holding them through the debugging process in comments is a better solution before posting an answer. The reason I say this is because someone who is fairly new to VBA is going to see this answer and grab it and not bother taking the more difficult path of following our instructions to get more info to us, it sets them up as a coder to build poorly written code.

Comment: True. I'll put a strong disclaimer on top.